# Can't see comments on my blog

Tags: blogger, comments

I cannot see the comments under posts on my blog: `http://evamilano.blogspot.com/`

If you check out any of my posts you will see that it says I have a certain number of comments but none of them appears.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I checked your blog, comment numbers are showing instead of real comments on the blog post.
You can recover all your comments by following these steps:

1. First of all backup or restore your Blogger Template
2. Go to Blogger Dashboard > Template > Edit HTML
3. Click on "Revert widget templates to default" button, appears in right mid.
4. A window will open, check the box of "Blog1"
5. Now click on "Revert Selected Widget" appears in orange color.

That's it. Now you can see all your comments are showing.